# What does { ...obj1, obj2 } do exactly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex, ecmascript-2018

Let's say we have two objects:

```
const state = {
  fishes: { /* some obj data */ },
  animals: { /* some obj data  */ }

const animals = { /* some NEW data */ }
```

In Vuex there is a method replaceState(), which according to the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#replacestate) takes one argument and replaces the state with that object.

What will be the result of the following:

```
replaceState({ ...state, animals })
```

More specifically, what does `{ ...state, animals }` do exactly?

To bring some context, I took this example from the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815876/how-to-deep-clone-the-state-and-roll-back-in-vuex?noredirect=1&lq=1) question. In that question, the user wanted to replace the `animals` property of the state with the new object `animals`.

I'm not sure if this is relevant to Vuex / Vue.js, or is it a pure JS question, but I'll tag it with vue.js anyway.

Comment: `{ ... }` is a object spread operator

Comment: I think you're looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-do-these-three-dots-in-react-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually from ECMAScript 2018's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) and ECMAScript 2015's [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

`{ ...state, animals }` creates a shallow copy of the `state` object, with a new property called `animals` (with the value of animals object within it).

Since you are a Vuex user, this conforms to the rule of [immutable update pattern](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays)s, which is to prevent the 'original' state object from being altered or mutated. You should read up on the ways of handling common operations such as add/update/delete, using the immutable pattern.

Comment: Just fyi, array spread is not same as Object spread. Object spread is a part of ES7 and while array spread is of ES6

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for pointing that out! It does indeed get confusing at times since spread applies for both objects and arrays after the proposals.

Comment: "with a new property called animals" - but if the state object already contains a property animals, will it get overwritten? Also, doesn't the destructuring result in multiple parameters passed to the replaceState() function in my example?

Comment: @NikolayDyankov yes, I believe it does. It in facts create a shallow copy from the 'original' state object. You can try testing it out by mutating the copied object and run console.log() on both of them to see the differences!

Comment: However, I have to bring your attention to the fact that, if `animals` is a nested object, you will have to shallow copy the various levels of it. This link has an excellent example https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#correct-approach-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data . I hope I am not boring you too much with all these URLs, but it is essential for you to understand this important concept.

Comment: I can try to have the animals object only one layer deep, but I will need to have arrays for a value of a property eventually, and that will need deep cloning of the animals object. As far as I'm aware, arrays are also objects and references are kept in a shallow copy of the parent object. Correct?

Comment: @NikolayDyankov yes, precisely. If you are updating a specific item in the array, you will need to return that updated item (the item you want to update), and the other existing items in the array.

Answer (score 2):

It means `Object.assign({}, state, { animals: animals} }`.

Comment: This is more of a comment. It would help readers if you add explanation as to what is happening, What's its purpose etc

Comment: As far as I know Object.assign() makes a shallow merge of two objects, but why are you destructuring the second one?

Comment: Actually, I am not destructuring the second one, but using the old, verbose ES5 object notation.

Comment: Ohhh right. I started to see destructuring everywhere lol

Answer (score 2):

What is does is it *spreads* all the properties of `state` into the new object - making a shallow copy. All the properties in the original object (`state`) will be copied into the new object (the one you're passing into `replaceState`). Here's a simple demonstration:

```js
let obj1 = { obj: "1" };
let obj2 = { ...obj1, obj2: true };
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

The `animals` bit is [ES6 property shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), and will essentially do this:

```
animals: animals
```

It's just cleaner syntax.