# I am learning react and have problem in following line

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and get stuck in the following line of code:

const { favourites } = this.state

Can someone please help me?

Comment: It's equivalent to `const favourites = this.state.favourites`. Read about Destructuring assignment https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does { ...obj1, obj2 } do exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685270/what-does-obj1-obj2-do-exactly)

Answer (score 2):

that isn't React-specific, it is a JavaScript (ES6) feature called destructuring:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that the const favorites is equal to the value of favorites in the state of the component. So if the value of favorites is 22 in the state, the const favorite is equal to 22.

`const { favourites } = this.state`

is same as

`const favourites = this.state.favourites`

Comment: But in my case state={filterText:'Hello', favourites:23}. In this case, what is the value of const favourites?

Comment: @Sachin the value of `const favourites` will be `23`

Answer (score 0):

Also, an important note is that by using const, you're making the state.favorites prop read-only.  Also, you can use it for any object.  Let's say I had an employee object with employeeId, lastName, firstName props, etc.  Let's say I get an array of employee objects, I can use this construct to greatly simplify the code.

```
render() {  
  const {UserName, EmailAddress, AccountCreated, PasswordChanged, AccountName,
    Locked, Enabled} = this.props.ewdsUser; 

return (       
    <tr>
        <td>{UserName}</td>
        <td>{EmailAddress}</td>
        <td>{AccountCreated}</td>
        <td>{PasswordChanged}</td>          
        <td>{Locked}</td>       
        <td>{Enabled}</td>
```

This prevents me from having to do this:

```
render() {  

return (       
    <tr>
        <td>{this.props.UserName}</td>
        <td>{this.props.EmailAddress}</td>
        <td>{this.props.AccountCreated}</td>
        <td>{this.props.PasswordChanged}</td>           
        <td>{this.props.Locked}</td>        
        <td>{this.props.Enabled}</td>
```