# How to reset state at Vue after clicking backbutton at Browser

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using VueJs with vuex.
When I click back button of browser, I want to reset the data of state on previous link.
I appreciate if you give me some example.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: I asked at Vue. So it is different thing. I guess.

Comment: Plus, I asked about reset of state of Vuejs.

Comment: Oh - but still answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295340/how-to-clear-state-in-vuex-store

Answer (score 0):

According to [Going back to States like Undo Redo on Vue.js vuex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878329/going-back-to-states-like-undo-redo-on-vue-js-vuex)
 Create A Vuex Undo/Redo Plugin For VueJS